# Bind fine uploader instance to form submit

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm stuck at something that's probably very simple, but I'm a backend developer and I can't really into javascript ;)

I have a form with a file input:

```
<form id='my-form'>
    ...
    <input type='file' id='file-input' name='file-input'>
    ...
    <button type='submit'>
</form>
```

I want this file to be sent to S3 and submit. I decided to use [Fine Uploader S3](https://blog.fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser-3d9dcdcc0f33). Since I have existing UI, I think core mode would be suitable for me. So, according to fine-uploader docs, I need something like this:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic({
    request: {
        endpoint: "my_s3_bucket",
        accessKey: "MY_PUBLIC_ACCESS_KEY"
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: "/s3/sign/"
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

The question is: how to bind everything together? I.e. how to make fine-uploader actually run and upload a file to S3 on the form submit?

Comment: can you upload the file succefully or not?

Comment: No, I don't know where to place code of the uploader and how to bind it to my form.

Comment: it would be helpful if you show how you include the Fine Uploader

Comment: I have `<script src="{{ static_url('s3.fine-uploader.core.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my template. I have fine-uploader `qq` var, so I guess it's included correctly.

Comment: just add the code below the script

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Do you mean I should put my fine-uploader instance definition below the script? But how would my form know to use it? (or the other way - how would uploader know to run on my from submit)

Comment: If you load the fine uploader script under the head section of html, then your initiation script should come after it. Iniatiation script will identify the form based on the id of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh, I've found the answer - I needed to dig into in the [fine-uploader docs](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#form) a bit more.
Just specify a form field in fine uploader object:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic({
    form: {
        element: "my-form",
    },
    ...
});
```

Another option is simple manual binding:

```
$("#my-form").submit(function() {
    var file = $("#file-input").prop('files')[0];

    uploader.addFiles(file);
    uploader.uploadStoredFiles();

    // actually submit the form (return false to not)
    return true;
});
```